# Generic word for something that produces itself

Tags: expressions

Generic word for something that produces itself. For example, a factory of factories; a bibliography of bibliographies; a collection of collections.

Comment: Do you want an *adjective* or a *noun*?

Comment: Is it really making itself or is it merely make something of the same category?  Is a factory that makes factories that make shoes something that fits your request or is it only factories that make factories that make factories?

Comment: If you'd posted the results of your dictionary and thesaurus and search engine searches, and explained which you preferred and why the rest weren't suitable, that might belong here.

Until then, would you mind first asking some dictionaries and thesauruses and search engines, and explaining why the results aren't suitable?

Answer (score 1):

Recursive or self-replicating, the latter more literally means making itself. Recursive means reoccurring but not necessarily self-making

Comment: Thanks.. Managed to get the answer  - Autopoiesis   The term autopoiesis (from Greek αὐτo- (auto-), meaning "self", and ποίησις (poiesis), meaning "creation, production") refers to a system capable of reproducing and maintaining itself. The term was introduced in 1972 by Chilean biologists Humberto Maturana and Francisco Varela to define the self-maintaining chemistry of living cells. Since then the concept has been also applied to the fields of cognition, systems theory and sociology.